# What should I pass for the owner parameter to a dialog from a unit test?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am using the built-in unit testing in Visual Studio 2010.  The code below shows the basic structure of my unit test.

```
public void StartEditorTest()
{
    IWin32Window owner = null;
    var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    openDialog.Title = "Select file";

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog(owner) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        bool expected = false; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        bool actual;

        var myEditorForm = new MyEditorForm();

        // StartEditor does some initialization, calls ShowDialog(owner)
        // and returns a boolean
        actual = myEditorForm.StartEditor(owner, openDialog.FileName);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that the openDialog doesn't always appear as the foreground window.  It opens correctly, but nested somewhere in the windows z-order, and I have to Alt-Tab to find it.

I'd like to specifiy the Visual Studio IDE as the owner, but I'm not sure how to do it, or even if that's the correct thing to do.  I just want any dialog launched from my unit tests to be displayed in the foreground.

Comment: Just a comment: That isn't a unit test. Unit tests are meant to be self contained. You having to enter anything isn't "self contained".

Comment: Point taken.  I did that for ease-of-use (read "lazy") to be able to test different files.

Comment: In that case, you could simple add some code in that form that brings it to the front. I don't think, you can get the correct owner, because it will be an internal window of the Visual Studio. Maybe, you could try to use the main window of VS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ui testing frameworks that are better suited to this. Try googling for [.net automated ui testing](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=winforms%20ui%20testing#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=winforms%20ui%20testing&xhr=t&q=.net%20automated%20ui%20testing&cp=16&qe=Lm5ldCBhdXRvbWF0ZWQgdQ&qesig=fMDcEj4fmgUDO1I-CgYJDQ&pkc=AFgZ2tm7W-dHFU9HzEJI4-NT5CN4xg8SBp1HNUBh7qI0eUged37ymAeVUvtQBCYw4Z7kalTdg9we36hsyDed6KuO9danZcgVRA&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=.net%20automated%20u&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=38664e7e8c090ddc)